# How could I inject my own variable to a model class in Flutter / dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

### Background

Using the following tutorial:https://www.raywenderlich.com/5896601-flutter-networking-tutorial-getting-started

I'm building a listview from external JSON data.

I have this piece of code to create a model for a "library" that is built from my JSON.

```
class SiteLibrary {
  final List<MySite> dasite; // 1

  SiteLibrary({required this.dasite});

  factory SiteLibrary.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      SiteLibrary.fromJson(json.decode(str)); // 2

  factory SiteLibrary.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SiteLibrary(
      dasite: List<MySite>.from(
          json["appData"].map((x) => MySite.fromJson(x))));

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "appData": List<dynamic>.from(dasite.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}
```

It is being used in regards to a FutureBuilder

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: _apiResponse.getJSONfromTheSite(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Result> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data is SuccessState) {
                  SiteLibrary sitedatacollection = (snapshot.data as SuccessState).value;
                  return ListView.builder ...
```

### What I'm trying to achieve

What I'd like to do is make this code re-usable across my app by having the `json["appData"]` part as variable.  Specifically the `"appData"` part.  I want to be able to externally tell this SiteLibrary class to use either `"appData"` or a number of alternative fields, lets call them `"appData2"` and `"appData3"` for now.
Right now if I change the hard coding of `"appData"` to `"appData2"` it successfully retrieves a different set of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try introducing a variable `jsonKey` which defines which json key to read. Notice that it needs to be static since you're trying to use it in a factory method.

```
class SiteLibrary {
  static String _jsonKey = "appData";
  
  static set jsonKey(String val) {
    _jsonKey = val;
  }
  
  final List<MySite> dasite; // 1

  SiteLibrary({required this.dasite});

  factory SiteLibrary.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      SiteLibrary.fromJson(json.decode(str)); // 2

  factory SiteLibrary.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SiteLibrary(
      dasite: List<MySite>.from(
          json[_jsonKey].map((x) => MySite.fromJson(x))));

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    _jsonKey: List<dynamic>.from(dasite.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}
```

Comment: but how would I choose which _jsonKey to use from the "outside world"?  ie. I want to use this SIteLibrary class from a variety of different places and have it decide which _jsonKey to use based on where it called from or via an injected variable?

Comment: Before you call SiteLibrary sitedatacollection = (snapshot.data as SuccessState).value; you could call SiteLibrary.jsonKey = ...

Comment: "Error: Setter not found: 'jsonKey'".  Instance member 'jsonKey' can't be accessed using static access

Comment: We also need to make the setter static: static set jsonKey 
I'll edit the answer